# Sum of sharepoint list items in particular field

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have one list with cost field,and I have multiple items in my list .I have to get the sum of cost field in my aspx page. If I add new item then also the aspx page should calculate the sum of cost field ...how can i achieve it using javascript...anyone please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use OOB sum feature for your list view.

Demo:

[image]

[image]

Or, load list items and then calculating by JSOM script.

Demo:

```
window.onload=function (){
var url=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
 var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(url);  
  var TotalCost=0;
   //Get the web  
   var web = ctx.get_web();  

   //Get the List based upon the Title   
   var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Store Items");  

   //The Query object. This is used to query for data in the List  
   var query = new SP.CamlQuery(); ctx.load(list);  
   query.set_viewXml('<View></View>');  
   var items = list.getItems(query);  

   //Retrieves the properties of a client object from the server.  
   ctx.load(list);  
   ctx.load(items);  
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(  
    Function.createDelegate(this, function () {  

        var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();  
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {  
            var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();  
            //console.log(currentListItem.get_item("Price"));
            TotalCost+=currentListItem.get_item("Price");//cost field

        } 
        console.log("-------------------------------")
        console.log("TotalCost:"+TotalCost); 
    }),  
    Function.createDelegate(this, fail)  
    ); 

}
function fail(){
    console.log("fail")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Java script code from the asp.net application, after connecting to the the SharePoint list through the context object, need to get the list items. You can refer the below Java script code to do the sum up functionality.

```
for (var i = 0; i < monthChoices.length; i++){
        chartSeries[i] = [];
        var monthTotal = 0;
        for(var j= 0; j< arrItems.length; j++ ){
            if(monthChoices[i]==arrItems[j].get_item("Month")  && arrItems[j].get_item("Duration")!= ""){
                monthTotal += arrItems[j].get_item("Duration");
            }
        }
        chartSeries[i].push([monthChoices[i], monthTotal]);
        console.log(chartSeries[i]);
    }
```

Reference URL :

[SharePoint List : Sum of Column Values using JavaScript Client Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211346/sharepoint-list-sum-of-column-values-using-javascript-client-object-model)

Or

The below code :

```
function onItems(sender, e)
{
  var iterator=myTotalTimeItems.getEnumerator();
  var sum=0;
  while(iterator.moveNext()){
         var item=iterator.get_current();//retrieves current item from the collection.
         var num=item.get_item("Estimated_x0020_Time_x0020__x002");
         if(isNaN(num)) continue;
         else
            sum+=Number(num);
  }
  alert("Total estimated time:"+sum);
}
```

Reference URL :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6370dbf7-4494-4d79-b02a-647f7442cc6e/sum-column-value-with-javascript?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the sum value on a page, first create a 'Scripteditor' webpart on that page. You can do this by editing the page, clicking 'add a webpart', choose the 'Media and content' category and then selecting 'Scripteditor'.

Once it is created, edit the following code so the 'listName' variable contains the name of your list and I assumed here you have a column named 'Cost'. If your column name is different, change that also.

```
<p id="SumPrices"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var listName = 'LISTNAME';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'' + listName + '\')/items?$select=Cost');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json; odata=verbose');
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            results = results.d.results;

            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                sum += results[i].Cost;
            }

            document.getElementById('SumPrices').innerText = sum;
        }
        else {
            alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
</script>
```

Now click on 'EDIT FRAGMENT' in the bottom right corner of the webpart (in edit page mode) and paste the code there. Click on 'Insert' and close the edit page mode. You will now see the sum of all the prices on your page.